# Vuetable-2: Property or method "css" is not defined on the instance

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to get [Vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) to work in our solution. The demo works without problems. The difference is that we use a lot of different modules and I'm fairly new to front-end development and fail to see what the problem can be.

The difference between the demo and trying to set the demo up in our own project is this:

Demo
`import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable`
Our project
`import Vuetable from 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable.vue`

The reason for doing so is because if I do not (leave out the `.vue`), I'll get the following error:

`ERROR in ./~/buble-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./resources/assets/js/components/VuetableTest.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vuetable-2/src/components/Vuetable'`

But, with the extension in the import, I'll get this (in the browser console):

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "css" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
(found in component <vuetable>)`

`[Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <vuetable>:`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tableClass' of undefined`

Now I have the *feeling* it has something to do with me needing to add the extension to the import, something that is not done within the `Vuetable` files, for example `import VueResource from 'vue-resource'`.

Our `package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-advanced": "*",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "*",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "multiselect": "^0.9.12",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.0",
    "notifyjs-browser": "^0.4.2",
    "sweetalert": "^1.1.3",
    "vue": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13",
    "vuetable-2": "^1.2.0",
    "vuex": "^2.1.1",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^1.0.0",
    "wow.js": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.0.5",
    "pace": "0.0.4",
    "pace-js": "^1.0.2",
    "pusher-js": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

If I need to provide more information for anyone to even begin to try to help me, please let me know, as I do not quite grasp in what direction I need to look.

Comment: Can you show your VuetableTest?

Comment: I can't, sorry. Eventually we gave up and are now using Element UI. The issue lies deep within our configuration, as we use Buble-loader instead of Babel-loader, no standard webpack (but Elixir), etc. etc.